# Array error from psql: Array value must begin with "}" or dimension information

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

I have three tables:

1. **text: text in lines**
2. **trigram: trigram of all text lines**
3. **text_trigram: trigrams that a text line contains, intermediate table**

I tried to execute this:

```
create or replace function get_values(IN t_id integer[], IN tri_id integer[], OUT count_values integer[][])
as $$
declare 
    count_value integer[];
    rec integer;
    tri_n integer := array_length(tri_id, 1);
begin 
    for rec in select unnest(tri_id)
    loop
        select into count_value count(text_id) from unnest(t_id) as required_t_id(r_t_id) left join text_trigram on text_id = required_t_id.r_t_id and trigram_id = rec group by text_id;
        count_values := array_cat(count_values, count_value);
    end loop;
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

Execution was fine, after I executed this:

```
select * from get_values(ARRAY[9,210,999], ARRAY[621, 3266]);
```

the error message came out

> Array error: Array value must begin with "}" or dimension information

I tried below as well,

```
select * from get_values('{9,210,999}','{621,3266}');
```

and I got a error message:

> function get_values(unkonwn, unknown) is not clear

Comment: Why are you unnesting the input array `tri_id` twice?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, that was a mistake, it should be `t_id`, I've revised that

Comment: I _think_ the whole loop is probably completely unnecessary and this can be done with a single aggregation without the need of PL/pgSQL to begin with - but without an explanation _what_ you are trying to do there, this is really hard to answer.

Comment: your meat I can do on select instead of the loop? I am not sure, bacause what I need here is a two dimension array

Comment: Well, the result from a SELECT statement _is_ essentially a two dimensional "array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store multiple rows returned by the query into a single integer (the result of a `count(text_id)`) into an array (`count_value`) - that won't work.

You need to aggregate the values into a single array and put that result into the variable, as you have a group by, you need to wrap the query.

```
select array_agg(cnt)
  into count_value 
from (
  select count(text_id) as cnt
  from unnest(tri_id) as required_t_id(r_t_id) 
     left join text_trigram on text_id = required_t_id.r_t_id and trigram_id = rec 
  group by text_id
) t;
```

The `group by` looks extremely strange though, I wonder if you actually meant:

```
select count(text_id)
  into count_value 
from unnest(tri_id) as required_t_id(r_t_id) 
  left join text_trigram on text_id = required_t_id.r_t_id and trigram_id = rec;
```

---

You also don't need to unnest the array you want to loop over.

Your loop should look like this:

```
foreach rec IN ARRAY t_id
loop
...
end loop;
```

Comment: @heisthere: your loop over the array is also incorrect

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I meant your solution was fully correct. I will try your suggestion, it looks much cleaner

Comment: It's really hard to decipher what you are really trying to achieve there. Please ask a new question that includes some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.